# import 'useAuthenticator' from aws-amplify outputs "TypeError: window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function" when jest testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, aws-amplify, react-testing-library

I would like to know how to mock this kind of dependency's error. If I omit this import and comment out related source code, the test process is going to be fine. Already have got through [Mock Function Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions), but no idea what I should do.

*This project was created by CRA with template typescript.

App component.

```
import { useAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

const App = () => {
  const { user } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.user]);
  return (
    <div>{user?.username}</div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Test code here.

```
import App from 'src/App';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('First group',()=>{
  test('rendering App component',()=>{
    // App includes 'import { useAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';'
    render(<App/>)
    screen.debug()
  })
})
```

Error outputs here.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function

    > 1 | import { useAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
        | ^
      2 |
      3 | const App = () => {
      4 |   const { user } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.user]);

      at define (node_modules/maplibre-gl/dist/maplibre-gl.js:25:43)
      at node_modules/maplibre-gl/dist/maplibre-gl.js:35:1
      at node_modules/maplibre-gl/dist/maplibre-gl.js:3:81
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/maplibre-gl/dist/maplibre-gl.js:6:2)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react/dist/index.js:1:484)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.tsx:1:1)
```

Based on slideshowp2's answer, added setup and config file. But still hits the error. Both are located rootDir.

jest.setup.js

```
if (typeof window.URL.createObjectURL === 'undefined') {
  window.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn();
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
};
```

**UPDATE**
This PJ was created by CRA so it required to follow their rule. I finally resolved this by slideshowp2's answer and the correct location to put the pollyfilling code.

**src/setupTests.ts**

```
if (typeof window.URL.createObjectURL === 'undefined') {
  window.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn();
}
```

Comment: How did you use `useAuthenticator`?, please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), show the code of the App component

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated the code to simplify for reproducing error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [troubleshooting#jest](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/blob/c12e9f53b6ab4913435795c4e563c632cdc74d5f/docs/src/pages/%5Bplatform%5D/getting-started/troubleshooting/troubleshooting.react.mdx#jest)

As of `v2.15.0` of `@aws-amplify/ui-react` which included the release of Geo components, users of the Jest testing framework may run into the following error when attempting to run tests:

```bash
window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function
```

Please follow the steps below to resolve this issue.

1. Navigate to or create a Jest setup file for your project.
2. Add the following code to polyfill the unrecognized function in your Jest setup file:

`jest.setup.js`:

```js
if (typeof window.URL.createObjectURL === 'undefined') {
  window.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn();
}
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  //...
}
```

This is a known problem when using the jsdom library (a dependency of Jest) with a package that uses an unrecognized function. See [this issue](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1721).

Comment: the troubleshoot looks like correct, but still hits error. I've updated my code based on your suggestion. I'm new to jest testing so I might have some mistakes in config files. Could you see again?

Comment: I created this project with CRA so I needed to put the polyfilling function into setupTests.ts under src directory. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @iamippei Yes. You should put the jest setups in `setupTests.ts` file when you use CRA.